# How to render a component multiple times dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  return (
    <div>
      {
        ['heni', 'mezi', 'dave'].map(name => {
          return <button onClick={() => setName(name)}>{name}</button>
        })
      }
      {name && <NewWindowDisplayer><h1>{name}</h1></NewWindowDisplayer>}
    </div>
  );
}


// mock implementation.
// Actually this component displays its children
// in a new window using ReactDOM.createPortal API.
function NewWindowDisplayer (props) {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>
}
```

Whenever a new button is clicked, I want to create a new `NewWindowDisplayer` component, so that each users data will be displayed in a different window. If there is an open window for the name, I want to use that instead of creating a duplicate. Like for above example there will be a maximum 3 new windows for each names. But this implementation will create one `NewWindowDisplayer` and update it when its props changed.

In short my question is how to render a component multiple times dynamically, button click for this case. Though I can track the clicked items and render the component based on it(array of clicked items and then traverse to the array and render the component), `NewWindowDisplayer` is a bit complex and I don't want to render it every time when a new button is clicked.

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-sunset-li0co?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
export default function App() {
  // Prepare data
  const names = ['heni', 'mezi', 'dave'];
  const [show, setShow] = useState([])  // Set which to show

  // Render
  return (
    <div>
      { // Create button for each name
        names.map(name => (
            <button 
                onClick={() => setShow(shown => [...shown, name])}   // Add new name into shown
                key={name} // Also dont forget to use keys
            >{name}</button>
        ))
      }
      { // Filter which should be shown & map
        names.filter(name => show.includes(name)).map(name => (
          <NewWindowDisplayer key={name}><h1>{name}</h1></NewWindowDisplayer>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't want to create the component for the existing ones, since it has a bit complex logic in it. I only want to create a new component when new button is clicked.

Comment: this will create only for those which were clicked

Answer (score -1):

Maintain a collection and add users to it when new button is clicked. Create components by looping through the collection.